# What's the difference between #<MyClass:0x10f6a82d0> and MyClass?

Tags: ruby, self

```
class MyClass
  def fun
    puts self
  end

  def self.fun2
    puts self
  end
end

mine = MyClass.new
mine.fun
MyClass.fun2
```

The above code should print self twice, in which case they are both MyClass. However, the actual output is

```
#<MyClass:0x10f6a82d0>
MyClass
```

which are in two difference forms. I wonder if they are actually representing different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result is the string representation of an *instance* of MyClass, whereas the second result is the string representation of the class MyClass.

If you had made another `mine2 = MyClass.new` and printed it, you'd get a different hex identifier at the end to distinguish it from your other instance.

Answer (score 1):

`#<MyClass:0x10f6a82d0>` represents an instance of the class `MyClass`.  `MyClassf.fun2` returns the class itself.